# Closing Java FrameView

Tags: java, swing

Is there anyting similar to JFrame.dispose() for Java FrameView

I want that the FrameView should close when some action is performed

Comment: In the future please also add Swing tag while asking about Swing-related issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far a I know the FrameView you're speaking about extends JFrame, so the method is `dispose()` as well.

Here are the FrameView classes I found :
org.jmat.io.gui.FrameView => extends javax.swing.JFrame
org.jdesktop.application.FrameView => offer a method getFrame() which returns a JFrame

But giving the real name of your FrameView class would really really help here...

Comment: dispose does not exist for FrameView